Thermoelectric cooler control point
The two operating hot side temperatures in the Peltier module data sheets are 27° and 50°. When connecting the thermoelectric cooler, how do I get the device to operate at a specific hot side temperature?

Same way you control the cold side, use a temperature controller to measure the temperature and adjust the tec drive current to hit the set point. Note that using a tec as a heater often doesn't make a lot of sense compared to a normal resistor so what you're doing may not be a good idea.

You need a way to run the peltier power from a set temperature sensor with closed loop control (like a PID) You also must provide sufficient power I'm not drive the healthy to be on its limits where it's getting into a saturation mode.
If you run an open loop that's fine but it will not react to temperature changes and the heat flow will always be different. To determine what the temperature is open loop you would need to know the heat flow and the temperature of both sides or fix those values physically. This is hard to do so use closed loop control
